# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.rocksdb.Options on Windows 10

Tags: java, spring, docker, apache-kafka, rocksdb

I'm trying to run a microservice as a spring boot application which depends on RocksDB. Currently I'm stuck receiving an exception below.

Environment:
Windows 10 v.1809
OpenJDK 10.2
Build system - Maven 3.6
InteliJ Idea 2018.3.1
RocksDB:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.rocksdb</groupId>
     <artifactId>rocksdbjni</artifactId>
     <version>5.17.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Kafka (2.0) and Zookeeper are running in Docker container.

After the service is started, an exception is thrown for each kafka thread:

> Exception in thread "thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not
>   initialize class org.rocksdb.Options  at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.openDB(RocksDBStore.java:128)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.init(RocksDBStore.java:185)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ChangeLoggingKeyValueBytesStore.init(ChangeLoggingKeyValueBytesStore.java:40)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingKeyValueStore.init(CachingKeyValueStore.java:59)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.InnerMeteredKeyValueStore.init(InnerMeteredKeyValueStore.java:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueBytesStore.init(MeteredKeyValueBytesStore.java:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractTask.registerStateStores(AbstractTask.java:225)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.initializeStateStores(StreamTask.java:159)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedTasks.initializeNewTasks(AssignedTasks.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.updateNewAndRestoringTasks(TaskManager.java:250)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:810)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:771)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:741)

I've tried to use some older RocksDB versions starting with 4.9.
Set the ROCKSDB_SHAREDLIB_DIR environment variable manually.

Could somebody please share any ideas what is wrong and how it may be fixed?

[**UPD**]
I've added a parent pom file of the server, and a child pom file of the service I'm trying to run.

**Server**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>group</groupId>
<artifactId>server</artifactId>
<version>0.13.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>name</name>

<!-- Global Properties -->
<properties>
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
    <spring-boot.version>2.0.5.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>

    <!-- Maven Properties -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.build.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.outputEncoding>

    <!-- Maven Plugin Versions -->
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven-javadoc-plugin.version>2.10.4</maven-javadoc-plugin.version>

    <!-- Standard Dependency Versions -->
    <commons-collections.version>3.2.2</commons-collections.version>
    <commons-io.version>2.5</commons-io.version>
    <guava.version>21.0</guava.version>
    <hibernate-enhance-plugin.version>5.3.6.Final</hibernate-enhance-plugin.version>
    <hibernate-ehcache.version>5.3.6.Final</hibernate-ehcache.version>
    <hibernate-core.version>5.3.6.Final</hibernate-core.version>
    <java.version>10</java.version>
    <jms.version>2.0.1</jms.version>
    <log4j.version>2.8.2</log4j.version>
    <activemq.version>5.15.4</activemq.version>
    <activemq-core.version>5.7.0</activemq-core.version>
    <javax.inject.version>1</javax.inject.version>
    <json-patch.version>1.9</json-patch.version>
    <keycloak.version>4.3.0.Final</keycloak.version>
    <jaxb.version>2.3.0</jaxb.version>
    <liquibase.version>3.5.3</liquibase.version>
    <postgresql.version>42.1.1</postgresql.version>

    <!-- Standard Testing Versions -->
    <jacoco.version>0.7.9</jacoco.version>
    <junit.version>5.2.0</junit.version>
    <mockito.version>2.21.0</mockito.version>
    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.22.0</maven-surefire-plugin.version>

    <!-- Code-generating Tool Versions -->
    <org.mapstruct.version>1.2.0.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    <org.projectlombok.version>1.18.0</org.projectlombok.version>

    <!-- Kafka Properties -->
    <spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.version>2.0.1.RELEASE</spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.version>

</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-javadoc-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>aggregate</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>aggregate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>site</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-report</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <forkCount>4</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                <argLine>-Xmx2048m</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Common Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>${guava.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-collections.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-io.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jaxb.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>${jaxb.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
        <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Cloud Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-commons</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jackson JSON Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Json Patch support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-patch</artifactId>
        <version>${json-patch.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Testing Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>${mockito.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>${mockito.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <!-- Exclude JUnit 4 from starter-test (and all other related test-starter, i.e
             those for security and project reactor -->
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Cloud Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Boot Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-ehcache.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

**Service**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <artifactId>server</artifactId>
    <groupId>group</groupId>
    <version>0.13.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>service</artifactId>
<name>service</name>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<!-- Global Properties -->
<properties>
    <!-- Traffic Control Properties -->
    <tc.build.version>${maven.build.timestamp}</tc.build.version>

    <!-- Maven Properties -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.build.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.outputEncoding>

    <!-- Spring Boot Properties -->
    <start-class>ServiceApplication</start-class>
    <spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.version>2.0.1.RELEASE</spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.version>

    <!-- Kafka Properties -->
    <kafka-streams-test-utils.version>2.0.0</kafka-streams-test-utils.version>

    <!-- Cache Properties -->
    <ehcache.version>2.10.4</ehcache.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <compilerVersion>${java.version}</compilerVersion>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <compilerArg>
                        <!-- The MapStruct property forces to create component from generated mapper to look up in Spring IoC container -->
                        -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
                    </compilerArg>
                    <compilerArg>
                        <!-- The MapStruct property forces to create component from generated mapper to look up in Spring IoC container -->
                        -Amapstruct.unmappedTargetPolicy=ERROR
                    </compilerArg>
                </compilerArgs>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <!-- Custom AccessorNamingStrategy SPI implementation -->
                        <groupId>group</groupId>
                        <artifactId>core-lib</artifactId>
                        <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>aggregate</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>aggregate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>site</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Dropwizard Metrics + Prometheus Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
        <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Boot Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Framework Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Integration Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-jms</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Cloud Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Cloud Stream -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>rocksdbjni</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.rocksdb</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.rocksdb</groupId>
        <artifactId>rocksdbjni</artifactId>
        <version>5.17.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Keycloak Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-spring-security-adapter</artifactId>
        <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Testing Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
        <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-streams-test-utils</artifactId>
        <version>${kafka-streams-test-utils.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Code-generating Tool Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
        <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Ehcache Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>${ehcache.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
</project>
```

In case the dependency for RocksDB is not set in the pom file SpingCloud will use some older RocksDB version, 5.7.3 as I remember. And produce the same exception.

Comment: What jars from rocksdb does Kafka require? only `rocksdbjni` or others? Seems like you're missing a jar to me.

Comment: Problem is rather not related with docker, the issue is with dependencies, please add pom.xml file. You shouldn't add rockdb dependency directly

Comment: I've added the pom files, hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

It appeared, my issue was caused by

"java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Local\Temp\librocksdbjni6935746072594020003.dll: Can't find dependent libraries"

which was hidden by 15 duplicates of the exception I initially asked about.

The problem was resolved by installing the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable х64.
Please note, the 2015 package should be installed regardless all newer Redistributable 
versions you already have.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the issue is correct - missed "Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable" but I haven't had installed exact version - "Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable х64", and the similar environment works well without errors.

I have the following list of installed "MS C++ Redistributable" versions:
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable (8.0.61001)
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable (x64) (8.0.61000)
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable (x64) (8.0.56336)
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x64 (9.0.30729.4148)
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x64 (9.0.21022)
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x64 (9.0.30729.6161)
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 (9.0.30729.6161)
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 (9.0.21022)
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x64 (9.0.30729)
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 (9.0.30729)
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 (9.0.30729.4148)
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 (9.0.30729)
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2010  x64 Redistributable (10.0.40219)
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2010  x86 Redistributable (10.0.40219)

Comment: Hi, this sounds more like extended details of the problem than a solution. It was probably better to post this as a comment on the question than as an answer.

Comment: Right, but I have no enough reputation for adding comments, sorry.